# Gradle in Idea and private artifactory repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, artifactory

My project uses dependency published in company's private Artifactory repository. Here is build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven {
        url 'https://myhostname.com/artifactory/someproject-shared'
        credentials {
            username = 'mylogin'
            password = 'mypassword'
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle builds it well from console. But Intellij Idea has the issue. When trying to refresh the project it says: `Unindexed remote maven repositories found.`. And there it does not manage to update the repo: `Authorization exception retrieving nexus-maven-repository-index.properties`.  How to fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I accepted Idea's offer to skip repository updating and gradle built the project.